# Should the `artemis` tag be renamed to or a synonym of `artemis-1`?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have `artemis`, `artemis-program` and `artemis-mission` tags. The latter two are synonyms and have a clear usage intention (questions related to the entire program).

There are currently 7 questions tagged with `artemis`, but they are all specific to the Artemis I mission.

Hence, I want to suggest that that this tag should be renamed to `artemis-1`, and in addition we should have `artemis-2` and `artemis-3` tags similar to how there are tags for each Apollo mission.

Despite hanging around here for quite some years, I do not know if a tag can be renamed. If not, I guess creating the `artemis-1` tag and making it a synonym is the only option, but I wonder if that is a good synonym.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I renamed [artemis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis) to [artemis-1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-1), and I made [artemis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis) a synonym of [artemis-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis-program) so people won't recreate the [artemis](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artemis) tag.